# Spark Windowspec lag function calculating cumulative scores

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe with scores for each day and I want to calculate a cumulative running score for each user. I need to sum up previous day cumulative score with today's score on a new column, I tried the `lag` function for the calculation, but some reasons it is giving an error.

Here is the code I tried:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val genre = sc.parallelize(List(("Alice", "2016-05-01", "action",0),
                                    ("Alice", "2016-05-02", "0",1),
                                    ("Alice", "2016-05-03", "comedy",0),
                                    ("Alice", "2016-05-04", "action",1),
                                    ("Alice", "2016-05-05", "action",0),
                                    ("Alice", "2016-05-06", "horror",1),
                                    ("Bob", "2016-05-01", "art",0),
                                    ("Bob", "2016-05-02", "0",1),
                                    ("Bob", "2016-05-03", "0",0),
                                    ("Bob", "2016-05-04", "art",0),
                                    ("Bob", "2016-05-05", "comedy",1),
                                    ("Bob", "2016-05-06", "action",0))).
                               toDF("name", "date", "genre","score")

val wSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("name","genre").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)
genre.withColumn( "CumScore",genre("score")*2+ lag(("CumScore"),1).over(wSpec2)*2  ).show()
```

dataframe:

```
-----+----------+------+-----+
| name|      date| genre|score|
+-----+----------+------+-----+
|Alice|2016-05-01|action|    0|
|Alice|2016-05-02|     0|    1|
|Alice|2016-05-03|comedy|    0|
|Alice|2016-05-04|action|    1|
|Alice|2016-05-05|action|    0|
|Alice|2016-05-06|horror|    1|
|  Bob|2016-05-01|   art|    0|
|  Bob|2016-05-02|     0|    1|
|  Bob|2016-05-03|     0|    0|
|  Bob|2016-05-04|   art|    0|
|  Bob|2016-05-05|comedy|    1|
|  Bob|2016-05-06|action|    0|
+-----+----------+------+-----+
```

Error I am getting

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window Frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$()) must match the required frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1);
    at org.apa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `lag`, simply use a window partitioned on the user and then use `sum`:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)
genre.withColumn("CumScore", sum($"score").over(window))
```

Using the input data from the question, this will give:

```
+-----+----------+------+-----+--------+
| name|      date| genre|score|CumScore|
+-----+----------+------+-----+--------+
|  Bob|2016-05-01|   art|    0|       0|
|  Bob|2016-05-02|     0|    1|       1|
|  Bob|2016-05-03|     0|    0|       1|
|  Bob|2016-05-04|   art|    0|       1|
|  Bob|2016-05-05|comedy|    1|       2|
|  Bob|2016-05-06|action|    0|       2|
|Alice|2016-05-01|action|    0|       0|
|Alice|2016-05-02|     0|    1|       1|
|Alice|2016-05-03|comedy|    0|       1|
|Alice|2016-05-04|action|    1|       2|
|Alice|2016-05-05|action|    0|       2|
|Alice|2016-05-06|horror|    1|       3|
+-----+----------+------+-----+--------+
```

---

The problem with using `lag` here is that the column is used in the same expression it is created (the column is used in the `withColumn` expression. Even though it's the previous value that is referred this is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following approach:

```
val wSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("name","genre").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)
val test = genre.withColumn( "CumScore",genre("score")*2)
test.show()
val wSpec3 = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date")
test.withColumn("CumScore_1",test("CumScore")+lag(test("CumScore"),1).over(wSpec3)).show()
```

We need to define another window function, as we need not to specify row frame while summing up previous day Cumulative score with today's score on a new column.

You can refer:  http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.in/2016/04/spark-window-functions-for-dataframes.html

Comment: Is there a reason you have declared two Windowspecs, I am seeing only one being used.

Comment: Yes.. Its throws error 'org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function lag does not take a frame specification.;' as first window function contains .rowsBetween Clause